# Retrieve a mock from a mock repository with Moq or any other mock factory

Tags: c#, mocking, ninject, moq

How can I retrieve a mock object from a mock repository using moq?

I have an application (mvc2) that wasn't really designed from the first time to support test units, but I am trying to adapt it. 
I have a service locator that creates the desired types.

basically what I want to do using a mock framework is replacing the variables that represent services in a method with mock objects, then I want to retrieve that mock objects and set them up.

So:

```
private ApprovalLevel GetApprovalLevel(Fusion Fusion)
{
    var ScopeofService=ServiceLocator.GetInstance<IScopeofService>();
    var programs=ScopeofService.GetPrograms();
    ...    
}
```

In my test units I set the ServiceLocator to use a mock kernel that will mock up my **IScopeofService** this works fine. The mock kernel uses a mock repository sent as param 
MockRepository Moq, that will bind and create the desired mock for a desired interface.

Now I want to retrieve that mock in my test to setup a fake value to be returned for the `GetPrograms()` but I MockRepository doesn't have a get mock just methods to create new mocks.

Still he somehow keeps all the references to mocks because it has VerifyAll method.

Update

```
public MockNinjectControllerFactory(Moq.MockRepository mockRepository)
{
    Kernel = new StandardKernel(new MockNinjectServices(mockRepository));
}

public class MockNinjectServices : NinjectModule
{
    private readonly MockRepository _mockRepository;
    public MockNinjectServices(MockRepository _mockRepository)
    {
        this._mockRepository = _mockRepository;
    }

    // TODO MARIAN: Resolver should return actualy mock objects also to be able to set them.
    public void BindToConstant<T>() where T : class
    {
        Bind<T>().ToConstant(_mockRepository.Create<T>().Object).InSingletonScope();
    }

    public void BindMock<T>() where T : class
    {
        Bind<Mock<T>>().To(typeof(Mock<T>)).InSingletonScope();
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        BindToConstant<IPaymentInvoiceRep>();
        BindToConstant<IPaymentInvoiceBL>();
    }
}
```

And the test itself:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DemoControllerFixture
{
    readonly MockRepository _mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);

    [Test]
    public void Should_MyMethod()
    {           
        EvedServiceLocator.Default = new MockNinjectControllerFactory(_mockRepository);
        var sut=new DemoController();

        // now if my sut has something that will resolve as mock created by my mockRepository I would like to retrieve that mock and set up something on it.            
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what problem you're having.  Post the code in your test where you're attempting to setup the service locator, and try to clarify your problem a little.

Comment: Hi thx for answering I've posted an update regarding my code.

Comment: Looks more like a dependency injection issue and not a mocking framework issue to me. In DI you first need to "register" a dependency in a container and then let the framework "resolve" it at run time. In the source code that you have provided, I couldn't see IScopeofService being registered and resolved.

Comment: The dependency resolver has no problem creating a mock using the mockRepository, the mock is created. The problem is retrieving the mock after. The method BindMock binds a service to a mock object.So I do not have DI problem. The point is that MockRepository from Moq.dll V4.2.1402.2112. doesn't have any method to get a mock reference, instead it has methods like verifyAll().

Comment: Maybe I am wrong using the mocking framework like that, but I thought it would work. I have some NinjectSettings that will give me the concrete types and on the other hands some MockingNinjectSettings and a mockingkernel that will mock all private variables, members, that would normally resolve trough the service locator. And all I am trying to do is not to expose all those services that resolve trough service locator, as properties or inject in the constructor.

Comment: Any Ideas? Can I help with more code or something to clarify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Moq.Get()` to get the mock object from a concrete reference.  In code:

```
[Test]
public void Should_MyMethod()
{           
    EventServiceLocator.Default = new MockNinjectControllerFactory(_mockRepository);
    var sut=new DemoController();

    var scopeService EventServiceLocator.Default.GetInstance<IScopeofService>();
    var mockScopeService = Mock.Get(scopeService);
    mockScopeService.Setup(p => p.GetPrograms()).Returns(/* TODO */); 
}
```

Comment: Thx - Use of Mock.Get() helped with another issue recasting to mocked object